# Error finding a library libopenlibm when calling a julia function in python

Tags: python, julia, pycall

I am using python 3.7, from an anaconda distribution.

I am having problems calling some functions from julia using pyjulia.

below is a snipped of my code:

```
import julia
from julia import Julia
julia.Julia(runtime=r"C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia\Julia-1.4.2\bin\julia.exe")
from julia import SpecialFunctions

SpecialFunctions.polygamma(3,2)
```

the package SpecialFunctons introduces generalized polygamma functions that can work with complex arguments (as opposed to the polygamma from Scipy, which only acceps real arguments).

The issue is that, when I run the polygamma function, i run into the following error:

```
julia exception: could not load library "libopenlibm"
The specified module could not be found.
 Stacktrace:
 [1] gamma at C:\Users\Bruno\.julia\packages\SpecialFunctions\LC8dm\src\gamma.jl:573 [inlined]
 [2] polygamma(::Int64, ::Float64) at C:\Users\Bruno\.julia\packages\SpecialFunctions\LC8dm\src\gamma.jl:359
 [3] polygamma(::Int64, ::Int64) at C:\Users\Bruno\.julia\packages\SpecialFunctions\LC8dm\src\gamma.jl:566
 [4] invokelatest(::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at .\essentials.jl:712
 [5] invokelatest(::Any, ::Any, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at .\essentials.jl:711
 [6] _pyjlwrap_call(::Function, ::Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct}, ::Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct}) at C:\Users\Bruno\.julia\packages\PyCall\zqDXB\src\callback.jl:28
 [7] pyjlwrap_call(::Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct}, ::Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct}, ::Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct}) at C:\Users\Bruno\.julia\packages\PyCall\zqDXB\src\callback.jl:49
```

Which means that python cannot find the libopenlibm library from julia, which is probably necessary to run the function SpecialFunctions.polygamma. I cannot figure out how to make python see this module. The dll libopenlibm.dll.a is clearly in the folder where julia is installed. I tried reinstalling pyjulia, modifying the PATH, and calling other modules of julia (to see if this would actualize a table perhaps). However, I had no success.

Other functions that do not require this library (for example, SpecialFunctions.gamma(x)) do not have this issue.

So, the question is probably: how can I make so that python loads this particular julia library into memory?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you run `SpecialFunctions.polygamma(3,2)` directly from the Julia REPL? If it does, I would suggest opening an issue on [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/JuliaPy/pyjulia/issues).